# PHP RegEx replace string between two same delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
=== Ut enim ad minim veniam === 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
=== Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident ===
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I want to replace the part between `===`, like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<strong>Ut enim ad minim veniam</strong>
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
<strong>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</strong>
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I have looked at similar questions, but it offers a solution only for text between different delimiters, and it didn't work when the start delimiter is the same as the end delimiter

I tried this:

```
$string = preg_replace( "#>>((?!>[^=]).+?)>>#", "<strong>$1</strong>", $string );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$test = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
=== Ut enim ad minim veniam === 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
=== Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident ===
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

$test2 = preg_replace('/===(.*?)===/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $test);

print_r($test2);
```

Result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<strong> Ut enim ad minim veniam </strong> 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
<strong> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident </strong>
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

You can also add whitespaces to `preg_replace` first argument if You want

Answer (score 1):

```
$input_lines = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
=== Ut enim ad minim veniam === 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
=== Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident ===
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

$result = preg_replace('/===\s(.*?)\s===/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $input_lines);

echo $result;
```

Result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<strong>Ut enim ad minim veniam</strong> 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.
<strong>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</strong>
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```